# Column location of last matching value in dataframe row (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2,3,4], 2:[1,2,4,5], 3:[8,1,5,6]})

df1
Out[7]: 
   1  2  3
0  1  1  8
1  2  2  1
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
```

and I would like to create a new column that will show the distance the last column with a particular value, 2 in this case, from the reference column, 3 in this example, or return an NaN result is no such value is found in a row. Output would be something like:

```
df1
Out[11]: 
   1  2  3 dist
0  1  1  8  NaN
1  2  2  1    1
2  3  4  5  NaN
3  4  5  6  NaN
```

What would be an effective way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you break down `a new column that will show the distance the last column with a particular value` ?

Comment: What is the referenced column?

Comment: @jpp  Sorry for being unclear. I have a reference column and I want to know how many columns away from my reference column is the last observation of a particular value in each row.

Comment: Is the reference column always further to the right than all other rows?

Comment: @HarvIpan The reference column is column 3 in this example.

Comment: @Dux Yes, the reference column is always the furthest to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need subtract `3` (last) because reference column with column name of last `2`:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(int)

print((df1.columns.max() - df1.eq(2).iloc[:,::-1].idxmax(axis=1)).mask(lambda x: x == 0))
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

**Details**:

Compare by `2`:

```
print (df1.eq(2))
       1      2      3
0  False  False  False
1   True   True  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

Inverse order of columns:

```
print (df1.eq(2).iloc[:,::-1])
       3      2      1
0  False  False  False
1  False   True   True
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

Check column name of first `True` (because inverse columns, it is last)

```
print (df1.eq(2).iloc[:,::-1].idxmax(axis=1))
0    3
1    2
2    3
3    3
dtype: int64
```

Subtract by max value, but it also return `0` if value in reference column and if no value match:

```
print (df1.columns.max() - df1.eq(2).iloc[:,::-1].idxmax(1))
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it as quite helpful